# Objects and List

Tags: python

I am writing a Dog class such that each dog object created contains height and weight field variables. Each of these should be initialized randomly for every dog. Height should be initialized to a random float in the range [1.00,100.0]cm. Weight should be initialized randomly in the range [0.7,20]kg. It says there's a syntax error right after the line def_init_(self):

```
def_init_(self):
        self.height = random.uniform(0.00,101.0)
        self.weight = random.uniform(0.6,20.0)
```

I also need to write a function called makePack() that takes an integer parameter, n, and returns a list of n Duck objects.

I have this:

```
for count in makeFlock(n):
    n = Dog()
    n.attr = count
    Dog.append(n)
```

I'm not sure if I am doing this right.

Answer (score 0):

It could be the problem of single underscore in constructor definition. Try the following code,

```
def __init__(self):
    self.height = random.uniform(0.0, 100.0)
    self.weight = random.uniform(0.0, 20.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the underscore between def and init.

I don't see anything wrong with your second loop, assuming that your makeFlock(n) returns a list of numbers.